# How to display a table order by code (like 01, 02… then null columns)?

Tags: ms-access

How to display a table order by code (like 01, 02… then null columns)?

Using Access 2003 Database

Table

Name Title code Nationality code

```
Raja       05       03
Ramu       03      
Vijay      01       02
John       04       01
Roby       06  
Abilash    02       05
```

So on…,

I want to display a table order by title code, nationality code

In my “nationality code” field some of the columns are null, so I want to display a table order by title code, nationality code (like 01, 02… then null columns)

My query.

Select * from table order by nationality code, title code

```
Name      Title    Nationality
Ramu         03 
Roby         06 
John         04       01
Vijay       01       02
Raja         05       03
Abilash      02       05
```

But Null value is coming first in the nationality code, I want to display nationality code like 01, 02, 03, 05 then null values

Need Query Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Nz](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012288901033.aspx?pid=CH100728911033) function to provide a value for NULL columns, for example `ORDER BY Nz(Nationality,9999999)`

Note the `NZ()` will only work within the Access user interface. For a more neutral approach, you could try an expression in the `ORDER BY` clause e.g. something like

```
ORDER BY (LEN(nationality_code) > 0), nationality_code, title_code;
```

Comment: @Paul Dixon. I used Nz, But Display null value first, then number's.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those values are NULL rather than zero-length values? If they are, then you should replace them with NULL then set Allow Zero Length to false for the column or add a Validation Rule or CHECK constraint to do the same.

If they are NULL then this may be a bug. I assume you are using Jet 4.0, for which NULL collation should sort NULL to the end of the resultset. In which case, you need the workaround (i.e. currently selected answer).

A note on Nulls/ZLS: Access 2003 (or maybe it was 2002, which I barely ever used) changed the default in its table designer from AllowZLS: No to AllowZLS: Yes. It's very, very annoying.

Comment: A note on Nulls/ZLS: Access 2003 (or maybe it was 2002, which I barely ever used) changed the default in its table designer from AllowZLS: No to AllowZLS: Yes. It's very, very annoying.